# WebMatrix razor (C#) WebMail helper returning server error sending email

Tags: c#, email, razor, helper, webmatrix

everyone,

I am having a problem sending email in WebMatrix razor (C#).

The error I am getting is:

```
a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period......., etc. etc.
```

It works fine at my job, but when trying to do a demonstration on a different computer, it returns this error when a user tries to register and the confirmation email is trying to be sent.  It errors on the following line:

```
WebMail.Send(
                    to: email,
                    subject: "Please confirm your account",
                    body: "Your confirmation code is: " + token + ". Visit <a href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" + confirmationUrl + "</a> to activate your account. " +
                    "Once your account is confirmed, all you need to do is await administrator approval."
                    );
```

I have checked the following:

1. Made sure the smtp server name is correct "smtp.gmail.com"
2. Made sure I do, indeed, have the current version of WebMatrix
3. Made sure I have the WebHelper library.
4. Made sure the port was set to 25
5. Made sure that the correct email address and password is set up

I tried researching a few posts, but none of them worked.

Any ideas on what this might be?

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

I disabled Comodo in XP, but it still didn't work. I think I traced the IP Address that corresponds to the host that it says didn't respond, and it belongs to a server in Tyler TX, owned by Suddenlink (the computer's ISP), but since the email address that is set up is set up through Google, and I am trying to access their SMTP Server and not Suddenlink's should their server's really matter?  If it helps, I do know that 'their' outgoing (SMTP) server requires authentication. Could that have anything to with it?  Again, I am NOT using an email account that is setup through them, though

Comment: Did you verify that the SMTP server is reachable from the other PC? If ping is enabled on the SMTP server for that port that would be the first thing I tried when `Send` fails.

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, I did ping "smtp.gmail.com" (by name not number, so DNS is fine) and got perfect replies. I didn't specify a port, cause I don't know how to ping by name and port.  If it's this:  ping smtp.gmail.com:25  Then I tried that and got no response.

Comment: Sounds like a security issue. Is this different computer on the same network as the first one? Is the firewall allowing SMTP traffic from both machines?

Comment: @Silvermind, Well, it's not that. I disabled Comodo in XP, but I think I traced the IP Address that corresponds to the host that it says didn't respond, and it belongs to a server in TX, owned by Suddenlink (the computer's ISP), but since the email address that is set up is set up through Google, and I am trying to access their SMTP Server and not Suddenlink's should their server's really matter?  If it helps, I do know that 'their' outgoing (SMTP) server requires authentication. Could that have anything to with it?  Again, I am NOT using an email account that is setup through them, though

Comment: Your last response was probably meant for @BobHorn :) Have you disabled the firewall on the other machine, just to make sure it is not that?

Comment: @Silvermind, yeah it was, my bad, but to answer your question, yes I tried it with Comodo disabled.

Comment: Honestly, this may just be a Suddenlink (the ISP for that computer) thing.  They are really tight with what they let touch their smtp servers, but again, I have it set up to use a gmail account, and also their smtp server (smtp.gmail.com), so I don't know...

Comment: We recently ran into very similar problems with mail and SQL Server connections.  Eventually we identified the cause was with a firewall that had been configured to inspect packets between subnets in our network.